# phonegap access origin for images only in listview

Tags: cordova, configuration, phonegap-plugins

I'm wondering if it's possible to use SPECIFIC access origin. For example, in my database I have a URL for pictures which are displayed in my listview. In my text content I have a link to the URL of the original article. If I use access origin="*", then the link in my text content opens in a WebView and it crashes the ajax page loading. If I only allow access to my server, then the image doesn't get displayed in the listview.

My question is whether I can whitelist a specific URL. For example, the image to the links is something like www.example.com/res/images/ and the original page URL is www.example.com/news/. Is it possible to just add example.com/res/images to access so the images load but the original article opens in the browser?  I've tried many different combinations and haven't been able to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer to my problem...and I don't have to use workarounds like inAppBrowser or ChildBrowser for Android.

I learned that in config.xml access origin="...", you have to specify EXACTLY the website URLs.  If the website doesn't use www but only uses http://example.com, you have to put that exact URL in your origin...and you can also add http://example.com/res/images/ to only allow that part to be linked to and displayed in your app.  If you have a link of http://example.com/news/something, clicking on that URL will prompt a native browser window.

Doing it this way, the dynamically loaded content through ajax does not break and the app runs as it should.  I hope this will help someone!!!